# PHP echo through Ajax doesn't give style?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

**Got blocked.**

1. Created a php page with normal html, css, js and php.

   Inside of that file, wanted for the user to be able to see events accordingly to the selected date.
2. In order to do that, once the date was selected, the value associated that date would get posted into a php script.
3. Inside of that php script, the posted variable was going through some conditions and echoing the results.
4. Then, the result of this php script, would be displayed in the initial php page.

*Ok, so far so good.*

Thing is,
**Want the text to appear styled, which means, want it to allow styling classes.**

Did some research but can't seem to find any problem like that.

When you go to the page and write, for example, the following in input: 12/22/2016, you can see data being displayed. Problem is, it ***doesn't come anywhere close to styled***.

This makes sense, somehow, because the php script doesn't have mentioned anywhere to use those styles.

The styles are being used in the initial php page (html/css/js/php), where the results will be displayed.

Initially I thought the style in the results would be recognized because it is called in the exact same page where those style files are mentioned.

***What am I doing wrong?***

**This it the result of the php script:**

```
<h1 class="hero-header-otro">It works! dfgdfgdfg</h1>
```

*As you can see, it has the class called inside of the h1*

This is the ***javascript code*** that posts in the php script and displays the results in a specific div of the same page where this js code is, which is the php page mentioned all the way through this message:

```
    jQuery(function($) {

  $(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    display("Got change event from field");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'events_script.php',
      data: ({dates: this.value}),
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results-ajax').html(data);
        alert(data);
      }
  });
});
  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

**The CSS:**

```
.hero-content > h1.hero-header-otro {
    font-size: 4rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: check what are the output you are getting by keeping  console.log(); after success function..

Comment: Just because an element has a certain class, doesn’t necessarily mean there is matching CSS selectors that would affect the formatting of the element based on that. It might be that your selectors only target such elements when they have a specific ancestor, or a thousand other things. With the code snippets shown so far, it is rather impossible for us to tell you what you did wrong.

Comment: @SoniyaReddy no errors given

Comment: css was added to the message @CBroe

Comment: from the css, the parent element is `hero-content`, however from the ajax you're appending this content to the `results-ajax`, I'm confused

Comment: hero-content is the class of the div where the h1 is inside.
results-ajax is the location where ajax is displaying the results echoed from the php script.
Does that make sense @Roljhon?

Comment: In this code <div class="hero-content"><h1 class="hero-header-otro">dfgdfgdfg</h1</div> your </h1> is not closed. However, can you check once again that this is the result that's being appended?

Comment: thank you all, I've changed what's inside of the echo and now everything seems to work fine and display the right results. Might be that you were right @Armin , haven't noticed that initially

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it fixed. **This it the result of the php script:**

```
<div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">

                      <div class="container day-events">

                            <div class="row event-list">

                                <div class="event-list-time col-md-3 col-sm-3 center" style="background-image:  url(/lascruces_styles/img/events-img/event.jpg);">

                                    <p class="event-list-start-time">2016-12-22 00:00:00</p>

                                    <hr class="event-list-time-divider">

                                    <p class="event-list-end-time">2016-12-22 00:00:00</p>

                                </div>

                                <div class="event-list-info col-md-9 col-sm-9">

                                    <h2 class="event-list-name">dfgdfgdfg</h2>

                                    <p>Organized by <span class="event-list-organizer"><a href="#">yyyyyyy</a></span></p>

                                    <p class="event-list-description"><p>dffghfghgfhf</p></p>

                                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn more-info-list">More Information</button></a>

                                </div>

                            </div> 

                        </div>
```

This is the ***javascript code*** that posts in the php script and displays the results in a specific div of the same page where this js code is, which is the php page mentioned all the way through this message:

```
    jQuery(function($) {

  $(".date").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
      display("Selected date: " + dateText + "; input's current value: " + this.value);
      $(this).change();
    }
  }).on("change", function() {
    display("Got change event from field");
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'events_script.php',
      data: ({dates: this.value}),
      dataType : 'html',
      success: function(data) {
        $('.results-ajax').html(data);
        alert(data);
      }
  });
});
  function display(msg) {
    $("<p>").html(msg).appendTo(document.body);
  }

});
```

**The PHP:**

```
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo '<div class="tab-pane" role="tabpanel">
                      <div class="container day-events">
                            <div class="row event-list">
                                <div class="event-list-time col-md-3 col-sm-3 center" style="background-image:  url(/lascruces_styles/img/events-img/event.jpg);">
                                    <p class="event-list-start-time">'.$row['Start_Date'].'</p>
                                    <hr class="event-list-time-divider">
                                    <p class="event-list-end-time">'.$row['End_Date'].'</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="event-list-info col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                                    <h2 class="event-list-name">'.$row['Event_Name'].'</h2>
                                    <p>Organized by <span class="event-list-organizer"><a href="#">'.$row['Company_Name'].'</a></span></p>
                                    <p class="event-list-description">'.$row['Event_Description'].'</p>
                                    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="btn more-info-list">More Information</button></a>
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>';
        }} else { echo 'No results found.'; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using datatype html in ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'events_script.php',
  data: ({dates: this.value}),
  dataType : 'html',
  success: function(data) {
    $('.results-ajax').html(data);
    alert(data);
  }
 });
```